# Safety about investing through a broker like Degiro

Tags: stocks, index-fund, shares

I'm *really* new to investing. I don't believe in pension and support from the government that much, so I took things in my own hands.
I started off from [this blogpost](https://www.caniretireyet.com/stock-series/) and landed on [JL Collins' blog](https://jlcollinsnh.com/stock-series/) which drove me into starting to invest.

Right now I've started investing in an index covering the world market (from *iShares Core MSCI World*). I've done it through [Degiro](http://degiro.ie/).

My questions are mostly about safety in regards to my shares. When I invest in the index:

1. Do I buy pieces of shares from each company covered by the index? Or is it a piece of the index? What's the difference?
2. I buy it **through** Degiro but **from** iShares. Is that correct? If I compare it to buying crypto: If I keep my coins in the exchange where I bought it from (f.e. Bitstamp), then if something bad happens with Bitstamp, I lose my coins. Who is the safeguard in the case with the index shares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iShares Core MSCI World is not an index. It is an ETF which is tied to an index, the MSCI World index.

When you want to invest in that index, buying shares from each of the companies would be an option, but a quite complicated one.

In order to avoid this hassle, iShares (resp. BlackRock) takes this burden away from you (and thousands of other people). They buy the shares in the correct ratio and let you participate on this by selling the ETF.

This ETF is issued by iShares, sold on an exchange and bought there by Degiro.

If something bad happens with Degiro, there should be a kind of insurance by your government.

If something bad happens with iShares, the stocks they have associated with this ETF should be separated from their assets so they should be safe even if BlackRock goes south.

If something bad happens with all of the shares in the index at once, everything is lost. But then, your money is your least problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have bought an ETF, which replicates physically or synthetically, the index that it follows.
2. Yes, that is the correct way. You could see for example that DeGiro is regulated by the Netherlands Authority for the Financial Markets. Ishares is a product of BlackRock which is a well-known asset manager.

My guideline is to only buy ETFs from European or American stock exchanges, from companies with a certain experience in managing ETFs. I also tend to prefer physical ETFs because I personally better understand how they work.

Comment: TIL there are physical and synthetical ETFs. Lot's to read... :D Tnx